# Django annotate with multiple tables

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given the models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MemberAction(models.Model):
  member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  action = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  datetime = models.DateTimeField()
  points = models.IntegerField()

class MemberMention(models.Model):
  member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  date = models.DateTimeField()
  points = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get the top five Members with the most combined MemberAction and MemberMention points for a given week. I also want the query to return all of a member's MemberAction rows for the given dates. Any idea how to do this?

I got as far as the code below, but the number returned for `points_action` is incorrect. Oddly enough, when I remove the `annotate` call for `points_news`, it works correctly.

```
def index(request):
    today = timezone.now()
    week_ago = today - timedelta(7)

    ma_w_dates = MemberAction.objects.filter(datetime__date__gte=week_ago,datetime__date__lte=today)
    mention_pts = Sum('membermention__points', filter=Q(membermention__date__date__gte=week_ago,membermention__date__date__lte=today))
    action_pts = Sum('memberaction__points', filter=Q(memberaction__datetime__date__gte=week_ago,memberaction__datetime__date__lte=today))
    members = Member.objects.annotate(points_actions=action_pts).annotate(points_news=mention_pts).order_by('-points_actions').prefetch_related(Prefetch('memberaction_set', queryset=ma_w_dates))[:5]

    context = {'members':members}
    return render(request, 'data/index__text.html', context)
```